# Authentication of Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to authorise a new computer with Xamarin Studio.  When I do it generates the following error and states to contact Xamarin support with the following information.

> System.FormatException: One of the identified items was in an invalid format.
>     at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService.GetErrorWorkflow (Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.LicenseSyncResult[] results, Boolean ignoreSyncErrors) [0x00264] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2968/8dc6bca6/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/Activation/ActivationService.cs:762 
>     at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService+c__Iterator3.MoveNext () [0x00410] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2968/8dc6bca6/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/Activation/ActivationService.cs:654 
>     at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog.DisplayWorkflowStep (Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationWorkflowStep step) [0x0002c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2968/8dc6bca6/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/Activation/ActivationDialog.cs:463 
>     at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog+c__AnonStorey4.<>m__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x0005b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2968/8dc6bca6/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/Activation/ActivationDialog.cs:561

Comment: According to the official support pages they offer support on Stack Overflow and not by email unless there is one in your account page which for me there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens when you are using an older version of Xamarin with one of the newer MSDN / Visual Studio licenses. Simply, the old activation system in previous builds does not understand the format of the new licenses.

This can easily be solved by updating to the latest stable version of Xamarin.

Mac: Xamarin Studio -> Check for updates

Visual Studio: Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Other -> Check now

As a side note, we do offer support for activation issues for anyone via email - contact@xamarin.com

Comment: Thanks for that.  The amount of times I spent going around in circles looking for activation support must mean it's either well hidden or I'm blind.